# Reduce Transparency Keeps Turning Itself Off

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display

In the accessibility settings on Yosemite I have enabled the "Reduce Transparency" setting multiple times.  The reason I am turning it off is to try to fix the issues causes with the menu redrawing when multiple monitors are connect and eventually slowing down the machine to a crawl. Each time I turn it on and go back in and check it has turned itself off.

[image]

It seems to turn itself off if the external monitor is connected.

Why does this setting not work?

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe are likely caused by the preference not getting saved to disk. This is caused by a problem with the file permissions, or if the preference file somehow got corrupted.

If this is the case, you can move the preference file (I think the relevant one is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist`) from its location: this will cause the preference file to be recreated.

Of course this will work also for other preferences (though identifying the correct file isn't always as easy); remember to keep the file around (instead of deleting it) so you can restore it in case this fix doesn't work.